# Access missing settings in Developer options?

Tags: settings, menu, hidden

On my Moto C Plus (7.0), "Cool colour temperature" and "Picture colour mode" appear in Settings search results but don't show up once tapped in Developer options. Is there any way to access them if they seem to have been hidden or removed? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are the developer options enabled in the settings?

Comment: Sorry for the lateness of my reply, developer options are enabled but the two settings still don't appear. After reading [this](https://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-X/sRGB-Picture-color-mode-setting-not-persisting/td-p/1326939), I think it could be because my display isn't supported.